# Combobox if selected not working

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

I have a combobox where I submit a value when Onchange event is triggerd. But the 'if' won't work.
The ID and the 'selectedGebouw' are both visible on the screen combobox, but it won't let it as selected.

```html
 <select name="gebouwFilter" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="0"></option>
    <%
      set objRec = objCon.execute(QUERY)
      DO WHILE NOT objRec.EOF    
    %>
    <option value="<%=objRec("locationID")%>" <%if selectedGebouw = objRec("locationID") then response.write("Selected") end if %>>
        <!--  <%=objRec("address") &", "& objRec("place") %> -->
        <%=objRec("locationID") &", "& selectedGebouw %>
    </option>
  <%
   objRec.MoveNext
      Loop
      objRec.Close
      set objRec = nothing
  %>
</select>
```

Comment: Not sure about right syntax, not sure whether it matters but there seems to be a superabundant `>` in `...response.write("Selected") end if %>>`

Comment: Nop it isn't the first is %> closing the script the second > is closing the option

Comment: @JosefZ `<%` and `%>` are ASP code rendering blocks they are processed "server-side" before being sent to the client, the end `>` is the closing bracket for the static `<option>` element.

Comment: Found the problem! When getting the value after a submit and changed it to int (cint) fixed it

Comment: @Cageman Can you leave your comment as an answer please (not a [question edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/26907847/2)) so the question has a solution, don't worry about answering your own question it's [encouraged on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @Lankymart I see, it's through fault my poor arithmetician skills only... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED:
First changed the submited value to int fixed it:

```
selectedGebouw = cint(Request.Form("gebouwFilter"))
```